# Mockito Method calls

Tags: mockito

I have a DAO implementation class :

```
public class DataPollingDAOImpl implements DataPollingDAO {

    public List<String> getInfo(String id,String columnName)
{
 // some code which calls the database and retrieves data. 
 }
}
```

I have written a mockito test case as follows-

```
 public  class connection{
    @Mock private DataPollingDAOImpl myDao;

     @Test public void test() {         


        when(myDao.getInfo("520", "Hole"));                 

         }

    }
```

I created a mock database connection as well. However what shall I do to print success on the console to show a success case after calling myDao.getInfo() in test method?

Answer (score 0):

If you are mocking using @Mock then I suppose you want your mock to return a value, you specify how to return the value by:

```
when(myDao.getInfo(anyString(), anyString()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList("yourReturnValue"));
```

If you want to see if you have called your Mock, then normally @Spy is used and you write:

```
Mockito.verify(myDao).getInfo(anyString(),anyString());
```

And I do recommend you to use interfaces (as DataPollingDAO) and not implementations (DataPollingDAOImpl)